# How to use multiple selectors with routing in angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using routing with angular4. 
In my main-template I have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` selector,
which shows me the content of my `RouterComponentA`, which I am routing into.

Here is my main Template!

```
<head>Main</head>
<body>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
```

Now I would like to introduce `<secondselector>`, which would display another info

```
<head>Main</head>
<body>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  Some text
  <secondselector></secondselector>
</body>
```

In my `RouterComponentA` I would like to fill both: `router-outlet` and `secondselector`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'secondSelector',
  templateUrl: 'routercomponent.html',
})
export class RouterComponentA {
  private routertext: string = "This should be visible instead of second selector";
  private secondSelectorText: string = "This should be visible instead of second selector";
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not? it works for me perfect, I see the RouterComponentA twice.

Comment: The goal is to replace `<router-outlet>` with `routertext` and ´<secondselector>´ with `secondSelectorText`. Not to show the same output twice.

Comment: You should not do like this. First of all router outlet works for a reason. We are declaring all our routes in module and we are mentioning the component which that route takes. So if you need to do some UI things, just make those changes to the component html or ts files.

Comment: If you need an example, I can provide that :)

Comment: yes, please provide an example